# Laravel 5.2 and belongsToMany combined query?

Tags: laravel-5

Could you please help me with combined query (I am beginner in laravel)

I have 3 tables

**users :** `id and name`

**words :** `id and name`

**user_word** : `user_id ,word_id and level`

Each user have his own Words

With relation model

**Class User:**

`public function words()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Word' , 'user_word','user_id','word_id')
        ->withPivot('level');
    }`

---

**class Word**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User' , 'user_word','word_id','user_id')
    ->withPivot('level');

}
```

In the `WordController.php` i need to mack query of other users words but if the current Auth::user have the same words I want it to be excluded.

```
$words = $user->words()  
           ->paginate(10,["mword","tword","image","id"],"p");
```

this code gave me all the words for the Auth::user.

Thank you.

Comment: could you please elaborate your issue ? did you try anything to get the required result ?

Comment: do you want to exclude the words or user ?

Comment: If i have user name (yamen) and he has words ( one  two  three) and user ( tony) and he has words ( one two three four ) and i am login as yamen i want to have query to show the other user words but not like my words = ( four )/ thank you